# ASP.NET MVC Dropdown list to which category to search

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to code Dropdown list to which category to search, I have 2 items in my dropdown: SSNorTIN and Account Number, everything is working, I can already search, i just want to have more option to my search, please help

This is my code:

**Controller**

```
public List<CICO> GetCICO(List<SqlParameter> queryParams)
{
    List<CICO> cicos = new List<CICO>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = str;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 180;
            string q = " SELECT distinct i.ssn_or_tin,i.cusid,i.accountNo,i.dateTrans,i.transCode,i.transdescription_1,(i.debit) as amount,(coalesce(c.debit, 0)) as cashin,(coalesce(o.debit, 0)) as cashout,i.source";
            q += " FROM source_ips i ";
            q += " LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM source_cash_in_original where transCode = '966') as c ON(i.ssn_or_tin = c.ssntin or i.cusid = c.cusid or i.accountNo = c.accountNo) and i.dateTrans = c.dateTrans";
            q += " LEFT JOIN(select * from source_cash_out_original where transCode = '936') as o on(i.ssn_or_tin = o.ssntin or i.cusid = o.cusid or i.accountNo = o.accountNo) and i.dateTrans = o.dateTrans";
            q += " WHERE (i.ssn_or_tin = @ssn_or_tin OR @ssn_or_tin='' ) and i.transCode = '131' and (i.dateTrans between '1/22/2015' and '1/22/2015') order by i.dateTrans ASC";
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(queryParams.ToArray());
            cmd.CommandText = q;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (sdr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        CICO cico = new CICO()
                        {
                            ssn_or_tin = sdr["ssn_or_tin"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["ssn_or_tin"]),
                            cusid = sdr["cusid"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["cusid"]),
                            accountNo = sdr["accountNo"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["accountNo"]),
                            dateTrans = sdr["dateTrans"].ToString(),
                            transCode = sdr["transCode"] == DBNull.Value ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(sdr["transCode"]),
                            transdescription_1 = sdr["transdescription_1"].ToString(),
                            amount = sdr["amount"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["amount"]),
                            cashin = sdr["cashin"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["cashin"]),
                            cashout = sdr["cashout"] == DBNull.Value ? (double?)null : Convert.ToDouble(sdr["cashout"]),
                            source = sdr["source"].ToString()
                        };
                        cicos.Add(cico);
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return cicos;
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllCICO(SearchParameters searchParameters = null)
{
    searchParameters = searchParameters ?? new SearchParameters();

    List<SqlParameter> parameters = searchParameters.ToSqlParameterList();
    var cicos = GetCICO(parameters).ToList();

    var jsonResult = Json(new{data = cicos}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
    return jsonResult;
}
```

**models**

```
public class CICO
{
    public double? ssn_or_tin { get; set; }
    public double? cusid { get; set; }
    public double? accountNo { get; set; }
    public string dateTrans { get; set; }
    public int? transCode { get; set; }
    public string transdescription_1 { get; set; }
    public double? amount { get; set; }
    public double? cashin { get; set; }
    public double? cashout { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
}

public class SearchParameters
{
    public string ssn_or_tin { get; set; }
    public SearchParameters()
    {
        this.ssn_or_tin = string.Empty;
    }

    internal List<SqlParameter> ToSqlParameterList()
    {
        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ssn_or_tin",  this.ssn_or_tin??string.Empty));
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px" class="row">
    <label style="margin-top: 5px" class="col-md-1">Search:</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control input-sm">
            <option>SSN or TIN</option>
            <option>Account Number</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="txtSSN">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btnSearch" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="IPSCICODatatable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SSN or TIN</th>
        <th>Customer ID</th>
        <th>Account Number</th>
        <th>Date Transaction</th>
        <th>Trans Code</th>
        <th>Trans Description</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Cash in</th>
        <th>Cash out</th>
        <th>Source</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var table = $('#IPSCICODatatable').DataTable({
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-2'i><'col-sm-5'B><'col-sm-5'p>>",
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5',
        'print'
    ],
    "ajax": {
        "url": '/Home/GetAllCICO',
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.searchParameters = {};
            d.searchParameters.ssn_or_tin = $('#txtSSN').val();
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "ssn_or_tin", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "cusid", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "accountNo", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "dateTrans", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "transCode", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "transdescription_1", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "amount", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "cashin", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "cashout", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "source", "autoWidth": true }
    ]
});

$('#btnSearch').on("click", function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
});

});
```

Comment: here you have to pass more parameters like :  d.searchParameters.cusid= $('#txtcusid').val();

Answer (score 0):

Here you go you have to pass more parameter in your ajax call :

```
"data": function (d) {
            d.searchParameters = {};
            d.searchParameters.ssn_or_tin = $('#txtSSN').val();
            d.searchParameters.cusid= $('#txtcusid').val();
            d.searchParameters.accountNo= $('#txtaccountNo').val();
        }
```

And you will get all parameters in your action

Comment: What will my SQL Query look like?